# Why objects which placed close without any indent, have a space between each other in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to build a frame for my image in Fabric JS. This frame should be built dynamically to fit any size of the image.
To do this I use two images:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/QARFj.png - image for side
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnQpL.png - image for corner

I've developed an algorithm, which does it and it works! That's great.
But I have a problem with the positioning of pieces of the frame.
As you can see in my example, there is strange space between pieces and they placed not on the same level by Y axis. I'm very surprised because these pieces have the same height and they have correct values for left and top.
Anybody knows what can be a reason of this problem?
Thanks in advance

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene_Ilyin/gzjxhLtm/9/

```js
var sideObj = new fabric.Rect(),  
  frameSideTopImage = new fabric.Image(new Image(), {type: 'image'}),            
  frameCornerTLImage = new fabric.Image(new Image(), {type: 'image'}),
  imageSize = 172,// Size of the image (width = height).
  leftOffset = 100,
  topOffset = 100;
  
// Load image for corner.
fabric.util.loadImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnQpL.png', function (img) {
  // Set image and options for top left corner.
  frameCornerTLImage.setElement(img);
  frameCornerTLImage.setOptions({   
   strokeWidth: 0,
    left: leftOffset,
    top: topOffset
  });
   
  // Load image for side.
  fabric.util.loadImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QARFj.png', function (img) {
    frameSideTopImage.setElement(img);
    
    // Create canvas for pattern.
    var canvasForFill = new fabric.StaticCanvas(fabric.util.createCanvasElement(), {enableRetinaScaling: false});
    canvasForFill.add(frameSideTopImage);

  // Configure top side for the frame.
    sideObj.setOptions({
     strokeWidth: 0,
      objectCaching: false,
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      left: imageSize + 100,
      top: 100,
      width: 800,
      height: imageSize,
      fill: new fabric.Pattern({
        source: function () {
          canvasForFill.setDimensions({
            width: imageSize,
            height: imageSize
          });
          return canvasForFill.getElement();
        },
        repeat: 'repeat-x'
      })
    });
    
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var frame = new fabric.Group([sideObj, frameCornerTLImage], {
        strokeWidth: 0,
        width: 800 * 3,
        height: imageSize * 3,
        scaleX: 1/3,
        scaleY: 1/3,        
      }
    );
    canvas.add(frame);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.7/fabric.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sideObj = new fabric.Rect(),  
  frameSideTopImage = new fabric.Image(new Image(), {type: 'image'}),            
  frameCornerTLImage = new fabric.Image(new Image(), {type: 'image'}),
  imageSize = 172,// Size of the image (width = height).
  leftOffset = 100,
  topOffset = 100;
  
// Load image for corner.
fabric.util.loadImage('http://i.imgur.com/w41HYN3.png', function (img) {
  // Set image and options for top left corner.
  frameCornerTLImage.setElement(img);
  frameCornerTLImage.setOptions({   
    left: leftOffset,
    top: topOffset
  });
   
  // Load image for side.
  fabric.util.loadImage('http://i.imgur.com/3VqKv1O.png', function (img) {
    frameSideTopImage.setElement(img);
    
    // Create canvas for pattern.
    var canvasForFill = new fabric.StaticCanvas(fabric.util.createCanvasElement(), {enableRetinaScaling: false});
    canvasForFill.add(frameSideTopImage);

 // Configure top side for the frame.
    sideObj.setOptions({
      objectCaching: false,
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      left: imageSize + 100,
      top: 100,
      width: 800,
      strokeWidth:0,
      height: imageSize,
      fill: new fabric.Pattern({
        source: function () {
          canvasForFill.setDimensions({
            width: imageSize,
            height: imageSize
          });
          return canvasForFill.getElement();
        },
        repeat: 'repeat-x'
      })
    });
    
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.add(sideObj);
    canvas.add(frameCornerTLImage);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.7/fabric.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</body>
```

set `strokeWidth:0` , strokeWidth is by default 1, so it creates a border of width 1 .

Comment: Thank you. I've already tried it but it is not helped in my case.
I'm sorry, but I've reproduced not all conditions. Now, I've updated initial message. I use scaling and the problem is reproduced. Could you check it, please? Maybe you know a solution? Thanks in advance.